# Как в android расположить один элемент поверх другого?

Tags: android, webview, android-textview

Есть разметка xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".DollarActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dollarText"
            android:text="text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dollarButton"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dollarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="@string/compare"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

В программе, к которой относится эта разметка, WebView должно запускаться по нажатию кнопки, а до этого на экране должны располагаться TextView и Button.
Проблема в том, что когда я запускаю приложение, Button отображается, а TextView нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить
P.S. Я знаю, что можно вывести WebView в отдельной активности, но мне интересно, можно ли сделать это в той же активности, в которой находятся другие элементы

Comment: вероятнее всего textview находится под кнопкой, сделайте в кнопке такую штуку - `android:layout_below = "@id/dollarText"` и уберите центрирование в родителе, либо наоборот сделайте такое с текстовым полем, либо замените тип макета на LinearLayout и все будет в столбик

Comment: @Andrew, превые 2 способа, к сожалению, не сработали полностью, в третьем (там, где LinearLayout), WebView не выводится на весь экран

Comment: у вас webview на полный родитель растянуто, вам нужно все друг под другом разместить

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Две разметки, два фрагмента - первый выводится сразу, второй его заменяет по нажатию кнопки.
2. По нажатию кнопка и текст скрываются методом [`View.setVisibility(GONE)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)), дополнительно можно изначально скрыть `WebView` в разметке атрибутом `android:visibility="gone"`, а по нажатию показать тем же методом: `view.setVisibility(VISIBLE)`. Тот же подход можно применять и к контейнерам - вместе с ними будут скрываться/отображаться все элементы, размещённые внутри.
3. Программно удалить кнопку и текст из контейнера, создать и добавить `WebView`
4. Сменить разметку активности на другую методом `setContentView()` или создать `WebView` программно и заменить им разметку тем же методом. Очень упрощённый пример:

   ```
   WebView webView = new WebView(activity);
   activity.setContentView(webView);
   ```